# Basic positioning with 'here' api

Tags: android, android-fragments, here-api

I am new to Android development and I am trying to use 'here' maps api.

I have done successfully the integration between 'here' and my app, so now it renders a map.

My next step it to show current location using the PositioningManager provided class, using 'here' api for positioning:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/map-positioning.html

This is my MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Map map = null;
SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
Location currentLocation = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);


    mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(OnEngineInitListener.Error error) {
            if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {
                // retrieve a reference of the map from the map fragment
                map = mapFragment.getMap();
                map.setCenter(new GeoCoordinate(32.174149299999996, 34.8501949, 0.0),
                        Map.Animation.NONE);
                // Set the zoom level to the average between min and max
                map.setZoomLevel((map.getMaxZoomLevel() + map.getMinZoomLevel()) / 2);
            } else {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment");
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

It renders the map. Now I am having troubles using the PositioningManager. If I create an instance of this class, I will be blocked since its constructor is private.
And if I call this class, I cannot use most of its methods since they are non-static.

My question is how should I call / use PositioningManager with my app ?

Comment: If the constructor is private, it's either a singleton or its wrapped into a factory or builder. Or you're just using the wrong constructor

Comment: If it is one of these Design Patterns you mentioned, then still how do I use them in my code ?

Comment: The PositioningManager that you refer is a singleton. So when you read PositioningManager.start(LocationMethod) then you have to call PositioningManager.getInstance().start(LocationMethod).

The link that you have placed also states that "PositioningManager can be accessed by calling PositioningManager.getInstance(). "

You can actually see a basic positioning implementation in this sample code https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/blob/master/positioning/app/src/main/java/com/here/android/example/basicpositioningsolution/BasicPositioningActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

Summary: The PositioningManager that you refer is a singleton. So when you read PositioningManager.start(LocationMethod) then you have to call PositioningManager.getInstance().start(LocationMethod). The link that you have placed also states that "PositioningManager can be accessed by calling PositioningManager.getInstance(). " You can actually see a basic positioning implementation in this sample code https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/blob/master/positioning/app/src/main/java/com/here/android/example/basicpositioningsolution/BasicPositioningActivity.java